# Custom recurring event solution using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, 2019

I am working on a solution for booking all day event on calendar (not the SharePoint Calendar, but **Full Calendar JS** due to some customization's).

I have requirement like to create recurring event functionality as it is in default *SharePoint Calendar*.

I am using a SharePoint List to store items.

Please suggest me some solution using JS/jQuery.

Comment: Why not just use a default calendar list as the background list so save/read the data from? Then you'll get the built-in recurring functionality and just import the events to the calendar normally. Or are you using something else as the backend?

Comment: Actually I am looking for the frontend functionality of recurring event (Like 2nd & 4th day of every week), also for each event I need to check if the any booking isn't exist in the backend list(Functionality already working for single booking).